# Deserializing a specific JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, list, serialization

I have a serialized JSON string serializedClaims -

```
// The Claim here is System.Security.Claims.Claim    
var claims = new List<Claim>();

claims.Add(new Claim("MakerId", "939393", ClaimValueTypes.String));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "1956-03-08", ClaimValueTypes.Date));

var serializedClaims = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims);
```

Now I want to deserialize `serializedClaims` back to a List.

But when I  do this

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(serializedClaims);
```

I get an error with "Unable to find constructor...."

How do I deserialize this correctly?

**EDIT:** It was `List<Claim>()` to begin with all along. And the error I get is despite of it. How do I assign an empty constructor to this??

Comment: `new List()` is a method that you have wwritten?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Post _your_ code, copy paste it, not code that wasnt actually the code that was giving the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var claims = new List();
```

is not the same as the generic `List<Claim>`

Try changing your `var claims` to `var claims = new List<Claim>()`

**update:**

Try using a `JsonCreationConverter`: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm

```
    class ClaimsConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Claim>
    {
        protected override Claim Create(Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject)
        {
                var type = jObject.Value<string>("Type");
                 var value = jObject.Value<string>("Value");
              ....
                return new Claim(type, value);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize is using Reflection with it's basic usage.

First you should use the power of Generics by changing:

```
var claims = new List();
```

**With:**

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
```

Then, in order for it to work, you should make few adjustments for the `Claim` class.

1. Specify a Default (empty) constructor
2. Make all relevant properties **public** with **set; and get;**

Comment: Please see edit. Should I be creating a new class with empty constructor?

Comment: I've edited my answer by you question.

Comment: The Claim here is System.Security.Claims.Claim    so I am not sure how to specify empty constrcutors for this.

Comment: Then sorry, you will need another solution, If it is to use Mike_G answer, or creating the List using AutoMapper for populating it from a fixed scheme.

Answer (score 1):

In your code block below you attempt to create a variable called 'claims' by using `var claims = new List()`.

However you haven't told it what it is a list of. 
You must explicitly define if it is a list of `string`, `int`, `apples`, `pears` or `Claim`

**Instead:** `var claims = new List<Claim>();`

So your final code block should look as follows:

```
claims.Add(new Claim("MakerId", "939393", ClaimValueTypes.String));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "1956-03-08", ClaimValueTypes.Date));

var serializedClaims = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims);
```